# Powershell string replace running slowly

Tags: powershell, replace, resources

I have a tab separated file like:

```
tyuy    wqf fdfd
zx c    vbn 733t 601    asd
```

Last line is like `zx c[tab]vbn[tab]733t 601[tab]asd`.

I need to trim data before the first tab in a 2Gb file with some 100 characters per line.

I want to copy content of the file line by line after the first tab

```
wqf fdfd
vbn 733t 601    asd
```

I wrote a script that works on small test files

```
 powershell -Command "(gc in.txt) -replace '^[^\t]+\t' , '$1' | Out-File -encoding ASCII  out.txt"
```

However, it consumed 10Gb of memory and took hours to run. 
Isthere a way to make this script faster? A bat file for cmd.exe would work too. Python and Perl cannot be installed on that computer.

Comment: the `Get-Content` cmdlet has a `-ReadCount` parameter that may do the job for you. it limits the size of a batch of lines that is passed to the next pipeline stage and that may be enuf to ease the memory requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the `-split` operator to get the part after the first tab character.
Because you are working with a large file, these options may work better for you:

1. Using `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines`

   ```
   foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("D:\in.txt")) {
       Add-Content -Path 'D:\out.txt' -Value ($line -split '\t', 2 )[-1]
   }
   ```
2. But perhaps faster by using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`

   ```
   $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader("D:\in.txt")
   $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\out.txt")
   while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
       $writer.WriteLine(($line -split '\t', 2 )[-1])
   }
   $reader.Dispose()
   $writer.Dispose()
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Content` is inefficient for large files.  Using methods of the .NET `System.IO.File` class is a better way to go.

Check out this article for a comparison of different techniques: [Reading large text files with Powershell](http://www.happysysadm.com/2014/10/reading-large-text-files-with-powershell.html)

Comment: Method from the article completed in 30 minutes: 'powershell -Command "([System.IO.File]::ReadLines('in.txt')) -replace '^[^\t]+\t' , '$1' | Out-File -encoding ASCII  out.txt"' @Threo's method was light on resources, but it ran for two hours, then I killed it.